# Grails3/groovy error iterating a list where index 0 was removed

Tags: arrays, list, groovy, grails3

this is my first grails project, so sorry if it's a newbish question but I didn't find anything about it.

I'm using Grails 3.3.2 with mongoDB and the calls to the DB are made with GORM.

I created a method that receives a list of users to create a MAP with the users and their specific roles and render it in a view. Only the admin has access to this page and now I don't want for a logged in admin to have access to his privileges/role, in other words, an admin can ONLY change the roles for other admins.
This way the system don't be with no admin by mistake.

This is the method:

```
@Secured(["ROLE_Administrador"])
    def renderListUsers(def listUsers) {
        //remove o proprio utilizador antes de tudo!

        // THIS PRINTLN !!
        //println(listUsers)
        listUsers.remove(User.findByUsername(getPrincipal().username))
        def usersWithRole = [:]
        for (user in listUsers) {
            usersWithRole[user.username] = UserRole.findByUser(user).role.toString().split("_")[1]
        }
        render(view: "listUsers", model: [users: listUsers, userRoles: usersWithRole])
    }
```

This method is working perfectly, the issue is that as soon as I added the "listUsers.remove(...)" (line 7) to remove the logged in user I was [getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5553.png) and I didn't understand why, then I find out that the error only occurs if the user removed is in the index 0 of that list.

Now I found if I add that "println(listUsers)" before it just works always! Even if the object removed is in the index 0.

Is this a known error on groovy or what am I doing wrong? I don't want to leave that print there.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:
Got it to work! This way:

```
def loggedUser = User.findByUsername(getPrincipal().username)
        if (loggedUser in listUsers) {
            listUsers.remove(loggedUser)
        }
```

I knew that I needed to add this verification, but I didn't thought that it would resolve this.

Comment: Make sure that you dont modify listUsers in other places. Better to create new collection by def tempUsers = listUsers.findAll{it != User.findByUsername(getPrincipal().username)} and iterate it instead of original collection

Comment: Thanks, I already got it to work and edited my question with the answer. But I tried the way you said and it didn't change the list.